# adding data to service based database in C# visual 2010

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to add entries to a database, it shows that record added successfully but actually nothing goes to database. my code:

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

student std = new student();
std.name = textBox1.Text;
std.fname = textBox2.Text;
std.email = textBox3.Text;

db.students.InsertOnSubmit(std);
db.SubmitChanges();

MessageBox.Show("Record added");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it shows that record added successfully" ? put your code in try and catch and make a break a breakpoint in catch clause.

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string**, please?

Comment: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Db12.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True